# $gcd(f,f')$ where $f=cg_1g_2^2\cdot\cdot\cdot g_m^m$ the squarefree decomposition of $f.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

In the literature i found the following lemma:
Let $K$ be a field with $char(K)=0,$ $f$ a non-constant polynomial in $K[X],$ $f=cg_1g_2^2\cdot\cdot\cdot g_m^m$ the squarefree decomposition of $f.$ Then 
\begin{equation*}
    gcd(f,f')=g_2g_3^2\cdot\cdot\cdot g_m^{m-1},
\end{equation*} 
and $f/gcd(f,f')=cg_1g_2\cdot \cdot \cdot g_m$ is the squarefree part of $f.$

So i have $f'=cg_2^2\cdot \cdot\cdot q_m^m+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ cq_1\cdot \cdot\cdot mq_m^{m-1}=cq_2\cdot\cdot\cdot q_m^{m-1}(q_2\cdot\cdot\cdot q_m+\cdot\cdot\cdot+q_1\cdot\cdot\cdot q_{m-1}m)$. But then $gcd(f,f')=cq_2\cdot\cdot\cdot q_m^{m-1}$ which is different than in the statement of lemma. Personaly I think it's typo but just want to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, but the statement in the book is not a typo either. It seems your issue is that the description of $\gcd(f,f')$ in the book differs from your description by a factor of $c.$ This is not an issue, however -- in an arbitrary ring, the GCD of two elements (if it is defined at all) is only well defined up to a unit. It is a standard result that $K[X]^\times = K^\times,$ so $c$ is a unit, and thus the GCD description you gave and the GCD description the book gave are both correct.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring (with $1$), and let $a,b\in R.$ An element $d\in R$ is a *common divisor* of $a$ and $b$ if $a = d a'$ and $b = db'$ for some $a',b'\in R.$ A common divisor $d$ of $a$ and $b$ is a *greatest common divisor* of $a$ and $b$ if moreover any common divisor $d'$ of $a$ and $b$ divides $d.$ So, the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ is the "greatest" in the sense of the divisibility partial ordering on elements of $R.$ However, we can see that if $d$ and $d'$ are associates (i.e., $d = ud'$ for some $u\in R^\times$), then $d$ divides $d'$ and $d'$ divides $d.$ Therefore, if $d$ is a greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b,$ so is $d'.$ There is not necessarily a preferred choice of GCD of two elements in a general ring, like there is in $\Bbb{Z}$, but the *ideal* generated by any GCD of $a$ and $b$ is well-defined.

You can read more about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744305/definition-of-relatively-prime-polynomials-over-mathbbqx/3744321#3744321) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#In_commutative_rings). You might also find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain) interesting.